# Шоп-карточки- адаптация кода для нескольких карточек JS

Tags: javascript

Суть вот в чем у меня есть три карточки, но функционал отрабатывает только на одной когда я просто изменяю let circle = document.querySelector(".color-option");

Но мне нужно как то данную функцию изменить для того что-бы отрабатывало на трех отдельно карточках

```js
let circle = document.querySelector(".color-option"); //- полученый масив
circle.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let target = e.target;
  if (target.classList.contains("circle")) {
    circle.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    target.classList.add("active");
    document.querySelector(".main-images .active").classList.remove("active");
    document.querySelector(`.main-images .${target.id}`).classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: "адаптировать"? Может быть - "исправить"?

Comment: все верно исправлен!

Comment: Все неверно! *(нужно ещё 3 символа...)*

Comment: Что именно?
Данный код отрабатывает толь лишь на одной карточке - к другим его как применить не могу понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let circles = document.querySelectorAll(".color-option"); //- полученый масив
circles.forEach(circle => circle.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
 ...
```

Comment: Спасибо отрабатывает!!!
А как теперь сделать что бы отработало по отдельности на смену картинки: 
     document.querySelector(".main-images .active").classList.remove("active");
    document.querySelector(`.main-images .${target.id}`).classList.add("active");
  }

Comment: ну, хоть два слова объяснения написали. было бы, конечно, лучше написать боьлше…

Comment: @Alex_ZD "А ... теперь"? Я Вам не гном из "Путешствия Нильса с дикими гусями". А теперь - привести попытки сделать это самостоятельно.

Comment: Есть значит три карточки - для одежды, с полем выбора цвета - при нажатии на один из цветов происходит смена активного цвета и  соответствующей цвету картинки.  
так вот данный код выше: отрабатывает только смену выбранного цвета по отдельности на каждой карточке - но картинка же сменяется только в первой карточке в остальных не происходит изменений

Comment: @Igor - не судите так строго начинающих))